# Vsphere 5.5 reset root

Tags: vmware-vsphere, vmware-vcenter, vsphere-client

I would like to change the root password used to access our virtual environment, I am using the vsphere client (5.5) connecting to a virtual appliance but cannot find where I can change this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open the vSphere client...

- Navigate to "Local Users & Groups".
- Right-click on the "root" user.
- Select "Edit..."

From the dialog below, you can change the password.

[image]

---

Edit:

You can also change the password at the ESXi host's console:

Log on, then choose "Configure password".

[image]

---

Edit #2:

You've clarified that you're trying to change the root password of the [VMware vCenter Server Appliance](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2002531). That was not clear in the original question.

In order to change the password of the appliance's root user, you need to log onto its management interface at: https://ip.of.vcenter:5480/

From there, select the "Admin" tab and follow the prompts to change the Administrator user password.

[image]

Comment: Hi I dont have this option.

Comment: @JJJJNR Are you logged in as "root"? Either way, you can change the root password from the console of the server. See above.

Comment: Ok, a bit of background info, a consultant upgraded our vm farm (8 hosts) but while upgrading vsphere ran into some issues so he used the virtual appliance and since then he also changed the password to something none secure, is the option to reset the password not available on the virtual appliance.

Comment: @JJJJNR Changing the password of the Virtual Appliance is a completely different question. Can you tell me which use you're using to log into vSphere as?

Comment: yes I am using the virtual appliance and logging in as root.

Comment: @JJJJNR See the edit above.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the above method to change the root password if you ware aware of existing password. If you forgot the root password of vCenter server appliance, You can reset it

http://www.vmwarearena.com/the-ultimate-revelation-of-reset-vcsa-6-5-root-password-in-60-seconds/

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged on SE, as the answer becomes useless when the link dies at some point in the future. Please include the essential parts directly in your answer and only link to the source as reference.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.